# Connecting Teltonika device with Python over TCP

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to connect with Teltonika device (FMB1xx) with this code:

```
import socket
port = 12050
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('', port))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print('Connected by ', addr)
imei = conn.recv(1024)
conn.send('\x01')

while True:

    try:
         data = conn.recv(1024)
         if not data: break
         print (data)

    except socket.error:
         print ("Error Occured.")
         break
```

So far I've figured out that `conn.send('\x01')` doesn't work as it should, and device don't send the rest of data. There were a few questions like this, but none has a good answer. [Here you can find documentation of this device](https://sourceforge.net/p/opengts/discussion/579834/thread/6fd0ffe8/6213/attachment/FMXXXX%20Protocols%20v2.10.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be encoded and ordered (little-/big-endian) if you sending more then one byte. Use something like this:

```
conn.send(struct.pack('!L', 1))
```

About connecting to teltonika gps: https://github.com/Kein1945/GPS_Teltonika_Server/

Comment: Does this solution work? cause In my case after getting the IMEI number it hangs forever. @uglymaxweber

Answer (score 0):

like @uglymaxweber mentioned you have pack it as integer(four bytes) and on python3 you can use the built in to_bytes.

byteorder is little or big endian and the first parameter is the bytesize.

```
   response = 5 
   conn.send(response.to_bytes(4, byteorder = 'big'))
```